# Too Slow Rails App with SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5

this is my second rails project. I am not an expert on Rails.
i use `rails 5` , `postgre` , `ubuntu 14.04` , `nginx` and `passenger` for my blog app. ( I have just one blog post ). In my droplet i have 3 apps. 1 laravel and 2 rails apps. But just one of them has SSL.

My website is working on the server ( in production env ). Yesterday I installed SSL and now my site is too slow. I don't know if it is related with SSL or not but it's super slow. Sometimes i wait about 1 min. to load.

In a weird way sometimes site gets faster ( normal speed ) but generally slow. 
What can be the problem ? How can i solve this issue ?

My SSL nginx config :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name guclukal.com www.guclukal.com;
   access_log off;
   return 301 https://www.guclukal.com$request_uri;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/guclukal.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/guclukal.key;

  server_name guclukal.com www.guclukal.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  root /home/rails/public;

}
```

On same droplet i use 2 rails apps. Other project works normal.

I need help !

EDIT : when change my conf file with non-ssl version it works great !

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name guclukal.com www.guclukal.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env development;
  root /home/rails/public;
}
```

EDIT : i use this steps to create ssl :

1. mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
2. openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout guclukal.key -out guclukal.csr
3. i paste guclukal.csr to ssls.com to get files
4. cat guclukal_com.crt guclukal_com.ca-bundle > guclukal.crt  to create crt file
5. than i made my nginx conf file .

Comment: The development environment is often slower than prod. You might want to try running as `RAILS_ENV=production` to see if its faster. Just remember to setup your database first.

Comment: i changed it to production but its same , please check the speed :  www.guclukal.com

Comment: Can you pls confirm if both http and https sites are same ? I get different pages with and without https. BTW, the speed appears fine to me :)

Comment: try this : https://www.guclukal.com/. i did not redirect http to https version. Sometimes speed looks normal , but in admin section its very very slow. I cant upload a file. Sometimes pages also renders too slow. But when i disable https its very fast on everypage.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many css and js files. Try to `minify and precompile` it into single css and js file. `Install ngnix pagespeed` module on the server which also improves your site speed. Refer https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/ for ngnix page speed installation.

Comment: Can you tell me the droplet size?. What is your database?

Comment: i use digitalocean 1 GB Memory / 20 GB Disk ( 10 $ ) droplet , database:  postgresql